# Image Size CSS not working although it should

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, themes, datastax-astra

I am trying to adjust the image height size of the hidden cart.

I have inspected the website with Developer Tools of Firefox and Brave. It appears like this modification should do the trick:

```
.woocommerce-js ul.product_list_widget li img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 4em;
 height: auto !important; (was before 4em)
 margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 object-fit: contain;
```

}

It was not working so I have put !important, without any effect.

Any idea to help will be welcome!

Website can be tested :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW4rO.jpg)([www.chic-and-chic.com](http://www.chic-and-chic.com))

Marianne

Comment: I'm confused on what the exact issue is—when I inspected that same boot image in the devtools, using `auto !important` overrides the image height just fine.

Comment: It does work on the devtools but when I put it in the Additionnal CSS section on Astra Theme, it don't work.

Comment: I have managed to make it work! For some reason, I had to put CSS directly in the Astra Theme Child style.css. It was not working through the built-in CSS editor. If it could help someone else.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Marianne If you figured out the issue, you can go ahead and create an answer (it might help others who run into a similar problem)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work! For some reason, I had to put CSS directly in the Astra Theme Child style.css. It was not working through the built-in CSS editor. If it could help someone else.